# How to make a string converted function return value in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
fnOriginal = function(){
  console.log("hello");
  return 10;
};

var fun = new Function("fnOriginal()");
console.log(fun()); // prints undefined.

console.log(fnOriginal()); // prints 10
```

How would I make `fun()` return and print 10 like `fnOriginal()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously,

```
var fun = new Function("return fnOriginal()");
```

`new Function("code")` is the same as `function() { code }`. If the code's missing a return statement, the function won't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
fnOriginal = function(){
  console.log("hello");
  return 10;
};

var fun = new Function("return fnOriginal();");
alert(fun());
```

It will return 10.